# Workflow Manager CU2 --- application error when access /_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx

Tags: 2013, workflow-manager

upgraded workflow manager 1.0 to Workflow manager CU2, workflow works but my workflow status pages errors saying:Application error when access /_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx, Error=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

```
0x04F8  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.    at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)   881ee89c-aefa-a0bb-f8e8-f7863053225a
02/09/2015 14:05:48.24  w3wp.exe (0x1B98)                           0x04F8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InternalServerException: Exception thrown from the data layer. For more details, please see the server logs. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: 673df0ca-53be-4dc0-b24f-e4631ab9cd37. NodeId: MAB00035D04. Scope: /SharePoint/default/f4c56302-930b-44fd-bdf7-c81e06187a0d/3d86a5e1-f611-4953-995b-4cbb424d33cb. Client ActivityId : 881ee89c-aefa-a0bb-f8e8-f7863053225a. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.     at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.HttpGetResponseAsyncRe... 881ee89c-aefa-a0bb-f8e8-f7863053225a
02/09/2015 14:05:48.24* w3wp.exe (0x1B98)                           0x04F8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...sult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ClientHelpers.SendRequest[T](HttpWebRequest request, T content)     at Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InstanceManager.Get(String workflowName, String instanceName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowManagementClient.GetInstances(String serviceGroupName, Int32 offset, Int32 count, String workflowName, String instanceName, String monitoringParameter, WorkflowInstanceStatus workflowInstanceStatus)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider.GetInstance(Guid instanceId)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.ApplicationPages.WrkStat...  881ee89c-aefa-a0bb-f8e8-f7863053225a
02/09/2015 14:05:48.24* w3wp.exe (0x1B98)                           0x04F8  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...Page.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)   881ee89c-aefa-a0bb-f8e8-f7863053225a
02/09/2015 14:05:48.26  w3wp.exe (0x1B98)                           0x04F8  SharePoint Foundation
```

Installed Service Bus CU1,Workflow Manager CU2 to get to 1.0 refresh, Workflow Manager Client 1.0 refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this question:
There is possible bug in the Workflow CU2: Workflow dbs:
WFInstanceManagementDB
WFResourceManagementDB

needs to be provided EXECUTE permission for role "WFServiceOperators"

make sure you apply that for both db's. that will solve the issue.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/054d2a58-8847-4a6a-b1ab-05a79f49fe65/workflow-manager-cumulative-update-february-error

Thank  You