# Error Publishing Workflow SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, publishing

> Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run.
>
> ```
>  Microsoft.Workflow.Client.InternalServerException: Exception thrown from the data layer....
> ```

[image]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the event viewer for more details on error(under Applications and Services Log\Microsoft-Workflow\Operational).It seems there is problem in permission.

Grant permission of workflow manager service account in “WF_InstanceManagement_DB” and “WF_ResourceManagement_DB”.

[Workflow Manager CU2 --- application error when access /_layouts/15/wrkstat.aspx](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/131268/workflow-manager-cu2-application-error-when-access-layouts-15-wrkstat-aspx)

https://justsharingknowledge.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/sharepoint-workflow-2013-error/